# 2 hexagons that are not affinely isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, polygons

I'm reading a book that provides an example of two hexagons that are not affinely isomorphic. One is a regular hexagon, and the other is not.

The book defines two polytopes (in this case hexagons) being affinely isomorphic if there exists an affine map from one of their spaces to the other, that is a bijection between the two polytopes.

I don't have much intuition for how a hexagon for example would be affected by an affine map.

I know that line-segments go to line-segments. I suppose this implies that vertices would also go to vertices? But i'm not sure. In any case none of this tells me why not any two hexagons are affinely isomorphic.

Comment: When trying to prove that two things are not isomorphic, search for invariants and then compute them. I don't know what the particular irregular hexagon here is, but here is something you can try. Note that affine maps preserve intersections of lines. For the regular hexagon, there are 3 lines between the vertices that intersect at a point. These lines are determined as the lines between a vertex v and a matched vertex 3 edges over. All this data would have to be preserved by an affine map. I would guess that those lines do not intersect in the irregular hexagon.

Comment: Great. So affine maps preserve intersections of lines, and parallel classes of lines. What if I wanted to show two things ARE affinely isomorphic? Suppose they pass the parallel lines test and the intersection of lines test. How would I go about this?

Comment: @trynalearn generally speaking you would have to write down an affine map and check that it works.